# using a variable within a variable bash

Tags: bash

Hi I am trying to update a variable that has a variable in it's name and can not figure out how:

```
n=6
tot=5
        let abc6xyz="$abc6xyz"+"$tot"
        let abc6xyz="$abc6xyz"+"$tot"
        echo "abc6xyz $abc6xyz"
#  Works fine
        let abc${n}xyz="$abc${n}xyz"+"$tot"
        echo "abc6xyz $abc6xyz"


++ n=6
++ tot=5
++ let abc6xyz=+5
++ let abc6xyz=5+5
++ echo 'abc6xyz 10'
abc6xyz 10
++ let abc6xyz=6xyz+5
./calc_tots.tst: line 9: let: abc6xyz=6xyz: value too great for base (error token is "6xyz")`enter code here`
++ echo 'abc6xyz 10'
abc6xyz 10
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of things working against you. First, avoid the use of `let`, it is an antiquated shell feature. Instead use POSIX arithmetic `((...))`.

Next, `$abc${n}xyz` is expanded as `$abc` (which isn't defined) and `${n}xyz` which is `"6xyz"` and isn't *decimal*, *octal* or *hex* so it is a number too great for base.

Using POSIX arithmetic in bash, you could change your script, incorporating `((...))` as:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=6
tot=5

    abc6xyz="$tot"
    ((abc6xyz+=tot))        ## use arithmetic operators ((..))
    echo "abc6xyz $abc6xyz"

    ((abc${n}xyz+=tot))           ## then use indirection, e.g. ${!foo}
    echo "abc6xyz $abc6xyz"
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash -x /tmp/tmp-david/bashindir.sh
+ n=6
+ tot=5
+ abc6xyz=5
+ (( abc6xyz+=tot ))
+ echo 'abc6xyz 10'
abc6xyz 10
+ (( abc6xyz+=tot ))
+ echo 'abc6xyz 15'
abc6xyz 15
```

---

**Adding Indirection or `final=$((...))`**

In the comments you explain you wish to take the number to include as `n=` as the first argument (positional parameter) to your script. In that case to access the total value after all of your additions, either use indirection or assign the final result of `$((...))`.

For example, using indirection:

```
#!/bin/bash

((abc${1}xyz+=5))
((abc${1}xyz+=5))

foo="abc${1}xyz"

echo "abc${1}xyz: ${!foo}"
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash -x /tmp/tmp-david/redir.sh 6
+ (( abc6xyz+=5 ))
+ (( abc6xyz+=5 ))
+ foo=abc6xyz
+ echo 'abc6xyz: 10'
abc6xyz: 10
```

Or preferably just assign the result of the last arithmetic operation, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

((abc${1}xyz+=5))
final=$((abc${1}xyz+=5))

echo "abc${1}xyz: $final"
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash -x /tmp/tmp-david/assign.sh 6
+ (( abc6xyz+=5 ))
+ final=10
+ echo 'abc6xyz: 10'
abc6xyz: 10
```

Comment: Yes, that will work, or just use `((abc${1}xyz+=tot))` instead.

Comment: OK, don't add to my answer, the comments are fine.

Comment: Yes but the comments get strung together as 1 line:

Comment: I am receiving a bad substitution with both tries
((abc${n}xyz+=tot))
echo "abc${n}xyz ${!abc${n}xyz}" 
./tot.tst: line 8: abc${n}xyz ${!abc${n}xyz}: bad substitution

Comment: OK, I see the comments, please don't edit the answer. Don't use indirection here `${!abc${n}xyz}`, that is a bad substitution. If you need indirection, it is `somevar="abc${n}xyz"` and then access with `${!somevar}`, but the variable `abcNxyz` must exist. Please **add** (do not **replace**) your current version at the end of your original question so I can be sure I'm addressing your current problem.

Comment: David thank you so much for you help last week it worked like a charm.

Comment: I am facing a similar challenge assigning a text string to a variable now.

Comment: I am trying to keep it simple as follow:

Comment: loc=abc value='Jul 02 2018 12:01' echo ${loc}datetime results in abcdatetime eval ${loc}datetime="\"$value\""  echo $abcdatetime results in Jul 02 2018 12:01

Comment: is there a way to do something similar like ${loc}datetime=$(value); or $(({loc}datetime=$value))  I want to get away from using "eval" and the "\$value\""  Thank you again you have been very helpful  SteveO.

Comment: Avoid `eval`, especially when calling it on variable. Heaven forbid you have a script that has `privfiles="$1"; mycmd="sudo rm $privfiles"; eval "$mycmd"` and then the user slips and enters `-r /`... You can do something with as described in the question. You cannot assign directly to `${loc}datetime=$(value)`. You have to create `somevar=${loc}datetime` and then use indirection. Get away from doing this. If you are continually running up against this problem -- you are approaching scripting wrong. Indirection should be the *rare exception*, not the *rule*.

Comment: Thank you David yes I have that solution and removed the eval.

Comment: I changed the naming convention of the variable and am doing:

Comment: declare datetime${loc}="$value"